# I need Selenium JavascriptExecutor to return an element via jquery

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I am at my wits end with this and I'm sure the answer is simple but I just can't figure it out.

I've got a jquery selector that finds and element perfectly when I put this in the console of google Chrome:

```
$(".answer__label:contains('Yes')")
```

Now I want to use this to retrieve an element in a WebDriver test, so I'm using JavascriptExecutor in the following way:

```
private WebElement findByJSText(String text) {
    String script = String.format("return ('.answer__label:contains('%s')')", text);
    WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
    return element;
}
```

This gives the error, "missing ) in parenthetical".  I've seen references to this error all over, but none that seem to apply to my situation.

How do I massage this to return the element properly?

(please don't respond telling me to use driver.findElement(By.linkText), thanks)

ADDENDUM

Here's what my final working method looks like:

```
private WebElement findByJSText(String text) {
    //String script = String.format("return $('.answer__label:contains('%s')')", text);
    String script = String.format("return $(\".answer__label:contains('%s')\")[0]", text);
    WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
    return element;
}
```

I may add a 2nd parameter for a css string to make this more flexible.

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
String script = String.format("return ('.answer__label:contains('%s')')", text);
```

Your javascript code is error, where is the jquery `$` function? Correct js code should be:

```
String script = String.format("return $('.answer__label:contains('%s')')", text);
```

### Edit:

You have the `'` within another `'`. Thats the problem, I tried the following js code and its working fine for me:

```
String script = String.format("return $(\".answer__label:contains('%s')\")", text);
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I've edited it so many times I must have trounced it somewhere along the line.  ;)  This still gives me the "Missing ) after argument list" error, however.