# How to check firefox console output with Selenium/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I enter the following command into the firefox console I get 65. This is the number I want to check with selenium.

```
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total()
```

Is there anyway I can get selenium to check this?

I have tried the following,

To test out javaScript, (this correctly checks title),

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.title");
Console.Write(var);
```

I have tried, both failed.

```
String num = (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total()");
Console.Write(num);
```

&

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
String script = "$('grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total()";
String num = (String)js.ExecuteScript("return", script);
Console.Write(num);
```

I'm just using Console.Write to see the output.

Comment: I haven't done a lot with JSE but it looks like you are missing a `return` with the first query try. Have you tried, `String num = (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.total()");`?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802518/i-need-selenium-javascriptexecutor-to-return-an-element-via-jquery?

Comment: i've tried with the return but no luck. I've also tried String num = (String)js.ExecuteScript("return" + script);

Comment: If it were me... I would do something super simple with jquery in Selenium just to make sure it was working. Maybe something like `$(document).find("title").text();` and make sure it returns the correct title.

Comment: My first bit of code I posted was my test to make sure it works. I like your example though as it's closer what I want it to be. $(document).find("title").text(); works! I'll keep at it anyway!

Comment: Right.. I saw that the JSE works with javascript... I was just curious if there's an issue executing jQuery for some reason and a simple jQuery statement might help identify that was the issue instead of your actual statement. It does seem odd that it works in the browser but doesn't through Selenium. Maybe some missing escape? I don't see anything that jumps out at me though.